# Bootstrap won't work even after calling all the reqired files

Tags: bootstrap-4

i have done everything which is i downloaded the bootstrap and downloaded jquery and link the css to my html here is my code but the dropdown menu won't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drop Down</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Drop down</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">First item</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Second item</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Last item</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have uploaded the file here http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02136226215566363704
so that everyone and see and tell me what went wrong

Answer (score 1):

It's because although you have added the dependencies correctly yet bootstrap requires another library call popper.js Here is the error for your code

[image]

Even this is mentioned in the bootstrap documentation installation guide

[image]

to solve this add the ppoer.js dependency by downloading it or using a cdn link
Add it like the follows
[image]

Comment: where can i download ppoer.js? is this the one https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.15.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js

Comment: https://gist.github.com/FezVrasta/16c5d5e5ff1211922ddcf090c8454d74

copy and paste it into a file and name it popper.js and the reference to the  HTML document but be sure to add it after jquery reference

Comment: yeah the link you mentioned is also ok

Comment: i tried adding but still it won't work can you try. Even after adding  this unpkg.com/popper.js@1.15.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js and this gist.github.com/FezVrasta/16c5d5e5ff1211922ddcf090c8454d74  it didn't worked

Comment: ok just a second

Comment: I have added a photo please make sure that you add jquery first popper.js second and bootrap.js last the content in your link works fine 

unpkg.com/popper.js@1.15.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js – 827639478623784

Comment: even after using cdn <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  i am still getting the same error message which is TypeError: Bootstrap's dropdowns require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org/)

Comment: are you using it before bootstrap.js

Comment: same error even after you adding what your picture says does it work in your system? if it does can you upload those files

Comment: please use it in the following order

1 Jquery refernce
2 popper.js refernce
3 bootstrap.js rfernce

Comment: ok i will upload them

Comment: thanks a lot i hope it'll work

Comment: https://github.com/sathiraumesh/bootstrap4 
here is . alink go and download

Comment: thanks a lot dude it work just fine now

Comment: yeah ok its nice to help